# $S$ is a closed subset of $E'$, then $f^{-1}(S)$ is a closed subset of $E$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $E,E'$ be metric spaces, $f: E\to E'$ a continuous function. Show that if $S$ is a closed subset of $E'$, then $f^{-1}(S)$ is a closed subset of $E$.

I need to show that $C(f^{-1}(S))\subset E$ is open. Since $S$ is a closed subset of $E'$ then $C(S)$ is open in $E'$. Since $f$ is continuous then we know that $f^{-1}(C(S))\subset E$ is open. But we need to show that $C(f^{-1}(S))\subset E$ is open, so does $C(f^{-1}(S))= f^{-1}(C(S))$? Are they both equal?

Comment: Does $f^{-1}$ even necessarily exist on all of C(S) in $E'$?  I can think of examples where it does not.  Are you restricting $E'$ just to the range of S?

Comment: @BettyMock I am not sure. I just assumed since $S$ is closed and $S$ is a subset of $E'$ then $C(S)$ is open and it is also a subset of $E'$.

Comment: For any set $X$, let $X^c$ be the complement of $X$. If $f$ is any function, $f^{-1}(Y^c)=(f^{-1} (Y))^c$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So I am correct? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. You may need to prove the result. The proof is short.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How can I prove that?

Comment: Show if $x$ is in the left side it is in the right, and vice versa. Let $x$ be in the left. Then $f(x)=z$ for some $z\in Y^c$. So $z$ is not in $Y$. So $x$ is not in $f^{-1}(Y)$. So $x\in (f^{-1}(Y))^c$. Essentially the same calculation works in the other direction, can indeed collapse them into one argument, but probably shouldn't.

Comment: @AndréNicolas There is something here I don't understand -- likely my own confusion, but would appreciate help. Let E = R and E' = R. Consider f(x) = $x^2$.  Let S = [0,1]. How does $f^{-1}$ exist on $S^c$?

Comment: $f^{-1}(S)$ is the **set** of all $x$ that are mapped to $[0,1]$, so $[-1,1]$. Note that $f^{-1}(A)$ (the inverse **image** of $A$) exists for any $A$, whether or not the inverse **function** $f^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: yes, that clarifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S^c$ be the complement of $S$. Then $S^c$ is open, and therefore $f^{-1}(S^c)$ is open. We will be finished once we show that 
$$f^{-1}(S)=(f^{-1}(S^c))^c.\tag{1}$$ 
The relation (1) is indeed  true for **any** function.

For let $x\in f^{-1}(S)$. Then $f(x)=z$ for some $z\in S$. Thus $x\not\in f^{-1}(S^c)$, since $f$ cannot simultaneously map $x$ to an element in $S$ and to an element in $S^c$. It follows that $x\in (f^{-1}(S^c))^c$.

A similar argument shows that if $x\in (f^{-1}(S^c))^c$, then $x\in f^{-1}(S)$.